# why am not able to add a bitmap to the bitmap arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap

why am not able to add a bitmap in the bitmap array list inside asynktask.

```
public static class YourMoves_Players extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

//  static String yourmove_players[];
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        boolean failure = false;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
       int success;

       Log.d("login.on create","YOURMOVE_PLAYERS Background");
       try {
           // Building Parameters
           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

           params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("playerid", fb_id));//player_id
           Log.d("request!", "starting");

           //Posting user data to script 
           JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                  GETYOURMOVE_URL, "POST", params);
           if(json == null)
           {
            Log.d("json","json returning null");
               return null;
           }

           success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
           if (success == 1) {

            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

            Log.d("Notification","BEFORE FOR LOOP");
            Log.d("",products.length()+" LENGTH");
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    String yourmove_pid = c.getString(TAG_YOURMOVE_ID); 
                    String player_name = c.getString(TAG_YOURMOVE_NAME);

                //  yourmove_pic.add(Get_FB_Image.getFBImage(yourmove_pid));
                    Players player=new Players(yourmove_pid,player_name);
                    yourmove_list.add(player);
                    yourmove_id.add(yourmove_pid);
                    yourmove.add(player_name);
                    Log.d("Vs_facebook","going to add bitmap facebook image");
                    yourmove_pic.add(Get_FB_Image.getFBImage(yourmove_pid));
                    Log.d("Vs_facebook"," facebook image added");
            Log.d("User Created!", json.toString()+"CONGRETS");
                }


                Log.d("","AFTER FOR LOOP yourmove_id  "+yourmove_id);
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
           }else{
            Log.d("Login Failure!", "SUCCESS FAILED");
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

           }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       catch(Exception e){}

       return null;

    }
    /**
    * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    * **/


}
```

"yourmove_pic" is a bitmap array list and "Get_FB_Image.getFBImage(yourmove_pid)" is the method from where am getting the facebook profile image of a user. but my app get stuck before executing this line . am getting the log message that i am printing before executing this line.
so what is the problem please help

my Logcat message ----->

```
09-19 10:21:48.999: I/Choreographer(2115): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-19 10:21:49.300: I/Choreographer(2115): Skipped 194 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-19 10:21:49.350: D/Vs_facebook(2115): inside on start
09-19 10:21:49.390: D/(2115): Vs_FACEBOOK ON RESUME BEFORE ShowList
09-19 10:21:52.509: D/login.on create(2115): YOURMOVE_PLAYERS Background
09-19 10:21:52.560: D/request!(2115): starting
09-19 10:21:54.980: D/Notification(2115): BEFORE FOR LOOP
09-19 10:21:54.980: D/(2115): 4 LENGTH
09-19 10:21:55.000: D/Vs_facebook(2115): going to add bitmap facebook image
```

in my getFBImage am getting the profile picture like this

```
URL img_value = null;
img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+fb_id+"/picture?type=small");
fb_image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
return fb_image;
```

Comment: What error you are getting ? Please post your logcat also.

Comment: Is your `Get_FB_Image.getFBImage(yourmove_pid)` return `Bitmap`?

Comment: are you getting null pointer exception ??

Comment: It may throw an "OutOfMemoryError".

Comment: am not getting any exception, it was stuck at  Log.d("Vs_facebook","going to add bitmap facebook image"); and yes am getting the facebook image when am using this method to set image directly to the image view.

Comment: Have you initialized your Bitmap ArrayList or not?

Comment: static ArrayList<Bitmap>yourmove_pic=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();  yes i initialized it.

Comment: If you are not able to add Bitmap inside yourmove_pic, that means its static error !!!

Answer (score 0):

according to me,this should through memory out of error exception and to handle that,here are some links that will help you to resolve this:
[Out of memory Error using List,LinkedList and HashMap](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_29.html)

can handle [Out of memory Error using LRU Cache](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.ro/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `Get_FB_Image.getFBImage(yourmove_pid)` decodes a stream and return a bitmap. If that's the case maybe the decoding of stream to produce bitmap is not yet finished that why the app is stuck when getting the bitmap.

Comment: please see above i edited my post with the getFBImage() definition please tell what extra i have to add to store images in bitmap arraylist

Comment: You can add AsyncTask that will perform the decoding of the stream. In this case just inform the user that decoding of the profile is currently doing at the background. Just think proper words and sentence to inform the user. If I'm not mistaken Android avoid decoding from the stream in the main thread that's why it is good to have a background task (AsyncTask) to perform that decoding.